# How to do a Select Distinct when returning XML

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a a stored procedure that returns an XML, the problem now is that i want it to return distinct ClientID's but when I do this.. it says

```
The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
```

How can i do this? here is my Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientTable.ClientID,
                ClientTable.ClientAddress,
                ClientTable.RetailStore,
                ClientTable.PhoneNumber,
                ClientTable.City,
                ClientTable.Amount,
                (SELECT Rating = IsNull(AVG(Rate), 0),
                        NumberRates = IsNUll(COUNT(ClientID), 0)
                 FROM   ReviewsTable
                 WHERE  ReviewsTable.ClientID = ClientTable.ClientID
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
FROM   ClientTable
       INNER JOIN ClientTypes
         ON ClientTable.ClientID = ClientTypes.ClientID
WHERE  ClientTable.ClientID IN (SELECT myFreeTextTableID
                                FROM   myFreeTextTable
                                WHERE  FREETEXT(*, @Keyword))
        OR

       ClientTypes.ClientID IN (SELECT myFreeTextTableID
                                FROM   myFreeTextTable
                                WHERE  FREETEXT(*, @Keyword))

ORDER  BY ClientTable.Order ASC
FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS
```

Comment: Why do you need `DISTINCT`? You are selecting from the `ClientTable`.

Comment: What are your table relationships?  Using `DISTINCT` can be an inefficient way of getting a unique list.  It would be better to find where you have 1 to many relationships and prune them down at that location to only a 1 to 1 relationship.

Comment: As @Jonathan said. For example, why you have that `INNER JOIN ClientTypes ON ClientTable.ClientID = ClientTypes.ClientID`? You don't seem to use any of the `ClientType` columns in the result. Do you really need that JOIN?

Comment: oh sorry i missed one part... Corrected above

Comment: so I am looking for the Keyword in both tables.. but the same Client can be in both tables.. so it comes back twice but i want it once.. 

I can not modify the schema.. how can i select the distinct ClientID?

Comment: Can the `ClientID` exist in the `myFeeTextTable` multiple times? Are the `myFeeTextTable` in your `OR` condition the same table?

Comment: no the ClientID is not more than once in the myFreeText table

Comment: clarification : ClientID would be in myFreeTextTableID and also ClientTypeID is in myFreeTextTable

Comment: @user710502 I'm getting a time out error when trying to edit or post my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not even going to try to reproduce your schema or data, but what about this query?

```
;WITH ft AS
(
    SELECT ClientID = myFreeTextTableID
      FROM myFreeTextTable WHERE FREETEXT(*, @Keyword)
),
c AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        c.ClientID,
        c.ClientAddress,
        c.RetailStore,
        c.PhoneNumber,
        c.City,
        c.Amount,
        c.[Order]
    FROM dbo.ClientTable AS c
    INNER JOIN dbo.ClientTypes AS t
    ON c.ClientID = t.ClientID
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM ft
            WHERE ClientID IN (c.ClientID, t.ClientID)
    )
)
SELECT
    c.ClientID,
    c.ClientAddress,
    c.RetailStore,
    c.PhoneNumber,
    c.City,
    c.Amount,
    Rating = (SELECT COALESCE(AVG(Rate), 0),
                        NumberRates = COALESCE(COUNT(ClientID), 0)
                 FROM   ReviewsTable
                 WHERE  ReviewsTable.ClientID = c.ClientID
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
FROM c
ORDER BY c.[Order]
FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS;
```